# Curve connecting the north pole of a sphere to another point on the sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curves

> Consider the following parameterization of a sphere of radius $R>0$ given as $\Gamma:[0,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $(\theta,\phi)\mapsto (R\cos\theta\sin\phi,R\sin\theta\sin\phi, R\cos\phi)$.
> Now let $0<r<R$ and consider the upper part of the sphere $C=\{(\theta,\phi):0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi, 0\leq\phi\leq r/R\}$. 
> Show that the distance between $P=(0,0,1)$ and $\Gamma(Q)$ with $Q\in C$ is at most $r$.

Now my idea was to find a curve $\alpha(t)$ that connects $P$ and $\Gamma(Q)$ and then finding an upper bound for the integral $$\int_a^b ||\Gamma(\alpha(t))'||dt$$
But I can't seem to find a relatively easy way to find such a curve or even still to calculate such integral. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong approach?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at $\alpha(t) = tQ$ for $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @Didier shouldn't that be $\ \alpha(t)=(\theta,t\phi)\ ,$ where $\ Q=(\theta,\phi)\ .$

Comment: @lonzaleggiera You're right, I wrote that in a rush

Answer (score 0):

To show that the meridians are length-minimizing, note that the first fundamental form of the sphere in spherical coordinates (such as the ones you chose) is *diagonal*.  Therefore when calculating length, the integrand will be $$\sqrt{g_{11} ({\alpha_1}')^2  +g_{22}({\alpha_2}')^2},$$ where $g_{11}$ corresponds to your coordinate $\theta$ and $g_{22}$ corresponds to your coordinate $\phi$.  But $\sqrt{g_{11} ({\alpha_1}')^2  +g_{22}({\alpha_2}')^2}\geq \sqrt{g_{22} ({\alpha_2}')^2}$ from which the result follows.